# Associating two types together

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have some code [here](https://github.com/SmartBear/git-en-boite/blob/master/packages/command-bus/src/command-bus.ts) which implements the Command pattern.

```js
type Type<T> = Function & { prototype: T }

export class CommandBus<Context, Command> {
  private handlers = new Map<Function, Function>()
  private defaultHandler: Handler<Context, Command> = (_, command) => {
    throw new Error(`No handler registered for commands of type ${command.constructor.name}`)
  }

  constructor(readonly target: Context) {}

  handle<HandledCommand extends Command, Result>(
    commandType: Type<HandledCommand>,
    handler: Handler<Context, HandledCommand, Result>,
  ) {
    this.handlers.set(commandType, handler)
    return this
  }

  do(command: Command) {
    const handler = this.handlers.get(command.constructor) || this.defaultHandler
    return handler(this.target, command)
  }
}

export interface Handler<Context, HandledCommand, Result = void> {
  (target: Context, command: HandledCommand): Result
}
```

The tests for it are [here](https://github.com/SmartBear/git-en-boite/blob/master/packages/command-bus/src/command-bus.spec.ts) and some other examples of it being used are [here](https://github.com/SmartBear/git-en-boite/blob/master/packages/adapter-git/src/index.ts#L31) and [here](https://github.com/SmartBear/git-en-boite/blob/master/packages/la-boite/src/repos/local_git_repos.ts#L98).

I'm pretty new to typescript, and the thing I can't figure out is how to model the association between a Command (which in this CQRS-ish implementation of the pattern, is basically just a message) and the expected result type.

At the moment, we're having to specify the return type as we [call the handler function](https://github.com/SmartBear/git-en-boite/blob/master/packages/la-boite/src/repos/local_git_repos.ts#L99) but I feel like this could be baked into the type of the Command, and from there imply a return-type from the Handler).

I think I maybe need to use a tuple type, such that a command is defined not just as `GetRefs` or whatever, but as `[GetRefs, Promise<Ref[]>`. I'm not sure where or how to do this.

Comment: Now that you're honing in on a more concrete question it may be worth opening a new, more specific question. You could provide a few line example of what you want to be able to do but can't. The links to your github have been helpful for us figuring out what you're looking for, but it would be preferable to have the key snippets (e.g. the one where you `bind` to `do`) in the question.

Comment: OK, thanks for the feedback @alexanderbird. I've broken down the problem a bit more, and expressed the first, most fundamental aspect [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62151019/expressing-the-relationship-between-pairs-of-types-in-typescript).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could do something like the following:

```
class CommandBus<T, C extends { constructor: Function }, M extends [C, any] = never> {
    private handlers = new Map<Function, Function>()
    private defaultHandler: Handler<T, C> = (_, command) => {
        throw new Error(`No handler registered for commands of type ${command.constructor.name}`)
    }

    constructor(readonly target: T) { }

    handle<H extends C, R>(
        commandType: Type<H>,
        handler: Handler<T, H, R>,
    ): CommandBus<T, C, M | [H, R]> {
        this.handlers.set(commandType, handler)
        return this;
    }

    do<H extends M[0]>(command: H): Extract<M, [H, any]>[1] {
        const handler = this.handlers.get(command.constructor) || this.defaultHandler
        return handler(this.target, command)
    }
}
```

I've added an extra type parameter `M` to your class representing the mapping from input to output as a union of tuples.  When you call `new CommandBus(context)`, the value of `M` will be inferred as its default `never`, meaning that such a command bus cannot initially handle any commands.

Then when you call `handle()` on a value of type `CommandBus<T, C, M>`, you return a value of type `CommandBus<T, C, M | [H, R]>` where `H` is the type of the handled command and `R` is the type of the result.  Note that this expects you to use method chaining to add handlers.  For example, if you call `const newBus = bus.handle(x, y)`, you should stop using `bus` and start using `newBus`, since only `newBus` is known to the compiler to be able to handle `x` instances.

And finally, when you call `do()` on a value of type `CommandBus<T, C, M>`, it only lets you pass in a `command` of a type found in `M` (`M[0]` is the union of all handlable commands).  And the return value is the analogous result type (`Extract<M, [H, any]>` pulls out the one element of the union of `M` matching `H`, and then `Extract<M, [H, any]>[1]` gets the result type.

---

Let's see if it works, using made up stuff:

```
const b = new CommandBus({ a: "hello" })
    .handle(Date, (t, c) => c.getFullYear() + " " + t.a) 
    .handle(RegExp, (t, c) => c.test(t.a));
```

Here I'm doing method chaining so that the only `CommandBus` instance I have a name for is the one already set up to handle `Date` and `RegExp` values.  And here we go:

```
const d = b.do(new Date()).toUpperCase(); // string
console.log(d); // 2020 HELLO
const r = b.do(/hello/); // boolean
console.log(r); // true
```

Looks good to me.  Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEB4YD4oF4oDECuA7AxsAJYD2uUAZFAN5RgBOJwT8AXLFAL4CwAUH-gA2AQwDOoqAGESAWxnDcAEwBC2UUgA0UqBAAewCEom18ZUcHrZCJeuxwFiZLloCyO-YcUSA2pK0KQAF10KFwIADcIelRqPih4unoicOEDKAALBUVBKIkMMIB3KBdhMAR7QlJcLQrHXGQACgBKOISGZNToRQgAM2FsQWAACSyc2ygRpTHNKVQMBoB9LVM5LKb0GNaEhOB0xiLCqABRekZ6BoADADkSDNGoqHoIAHMicyiIRSgemygV+SMUBIPSgoEgUAAJNR-lkAHSmXDmSzWeiw3DCGQQTgXFq8bY8fh4hIIpFWZjnJ7CRRkQQgUHCejPCDAdgwda0AlbO5TRBDdwGQF+KAAJUaXO2MKUcEgrPgCCGyA04oSmR540m2SiMyGWlFSqJ8Sa7GkqyUqnUMC0QrcAB8oN4dSLApsDdtQek3rDVZr6KJYaJmQ1JYppRAtN6xutlfEnsBsPRyLs3gBuLmc13U+X8zwSFzeAAMzqDsgBinYQyNx309GEhAQLi0Dv8uCCyG8AEZgrFXRKzMBuT6Qkm-RHcrCmcBi6bFPC+8jyesbXbh7Dun0BsN7vRo49mfHyKPzivgAyJ8sS2s03x00RcAZ6H18NANdNJDAABpaIaSFwAEV1IThCQRCKC62wNCejLMsaH7ntO5Y-r+lbCtefACH2UAAEYhIcJqluaDS0MI7AAETpBAgiCCQJFcLi2xevcDS-p0WgQcs6xoKg+DjsyOCUQAmhADLNFAADUUA0TR4nALCwhRq6DE8g0wovEcuhgKxwDsRsfywgY5gQbJTRNKmhIkv2XwYJhq4kA0hzMQYzRNHpJAAKpgJA9CSGIEDNMmUAAPQBVASK3s86GIiQOSwlRzwNIoJmBcFABM+apRMRwADKZQA8hF5iPCE1nUg0AXkZRJABYlQVYSQUVCbg+X1TFJBxfQ1XBRY2AQHwQA)

Comment: This is great, and it almost works for me!

The thing I seem to be lacking, is the ability to pass the `do` function around, as I can't work out how to get this dynamically-created type signature for the function and use it elsewhere.

For example, [this](https://github.com/SmartBear/git-en-boite/pull/52/files#diff-0136ea0672943d7151aa03dd8342e34aR76) causes compilation errors, as the `refs` is typed as `unknown`.

Comment: Since that mapping is defined at runtime it won't be available at compile-time. Can you define all the handlers at the time you instantiate the `CommandBus`? If so, you can construct the `CommandBus` with an object mapping command types to handlers. Then you can probably use [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) to get the result type from that mapping object for calls to `do`.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you're looking for a way to change `handle` from

```js
handle<HandledCommand extends Command, Result>(
    commandType: Type<HandledCommand>,
    handler: HandlesCommands<Context, HandledCommand, Result>,
  ): CommandBus<Context, Command> {
    this.handlers.set(commandType, handler)
    return this
  }
```

to

```js
handle<HandledCommand extends Command, Result>(
    handler: HandlesCommands<Context, HandledCommand, Result>,
  ): CommandBus<Context, Command> {
    const commandType: Type<HandledCommand> = magic(handler)
    this.handlers.set(commandType, handler)
    return this
  }
```

Is that right?

---

If so, the short answer is "no". You need a reference to the class object for commandType to use at runtime as a key for the handlers. You can get the *type* of `commandType` from the `handler` argument, but you can't get a *reference* to the class object.

The distinction is between **type declaration space** and **variable declaration space** -- more on that in [TypeScript Deep Dive: Declaration Spaces](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/project/declarationspaces).

Since you can't get the class object from a type, any answer to your question will amount to re-arranging the code so the class object is passed in as a parameter in some other way -- but it will still need to be passed in to each call to `handle` somehow.

Comment: I think that was an initial instict I had, and your answer has helped it become less hazy for me why this is not possible. Thanks! 

What I think is realistic is a way to model the relationship between a Command and a Result such that, for example, you couldn't even register a handler for CommandX if it didn't return the Result that was mapped to CommandX.

So I'm looking for how to express / model that Command-Result relationship.

Comment: Great! Glad to help.