# Extracting from a Union Type when some have identical shapes / properties

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

I am trying to build an implementation of a CQRS-style command bus, where the interface to the command bus is a single function, `dispatch`:

```js
const result = dispatch(message)
```

The `dispatch` function's type signature is something like this:

```js
type Dispatch<Message, Result> = (message: Message) => Result
```

Imagine, for example, that we want to provide an interface to a Git repo. Some of the messages might be:

```js
class Clone {
    constructor(public readonly remoteUrl: string) { }
}

class Checkout {
    constructor(public readonly branchName: string) { }
}

class RevParse {
    constructor(public readonly branchName: string) { }
}
```

For each `Message`, there is a known type of `Result`. After some experimentation, I think the right way to express that "protocol" is like this:

```js
type Protocol = [Clone, void] | [Checkout, void] | [RevParse, string]
```

The `Protocol` is a union of tuple types, each expressing the relationship between a `Message` and an expected type of `Result`. In the example, only `RevParse` should be expected to return anything interesting - the others just return void.

To be able to figure out the expected `Result` for a given `Message`, I had [learned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61994541/12397979) that I can use the `Extract` utility type, like this:

```js
type Result<Message> = Extract<Protocol, [Message, any]>[1]
type Dispatch<Message extends Protocol[0]> = (message: Message) => Result<Message>
```

However, I've discovered that this seems to fail when two of the Messages have the same properties. For example, I can return a `string` from the `Checkout` message. I'm assuming this is because `Extract` matches both `Checkout` and `RevParse` when given the `Checkout` type to look up the right `Result`, since both types look like `{ branchName: string}`.

```js
// should fail with type error because the protocol says Checkout should return void.
const checkoutResult: Result<Checkout> = 'string'
// const checkoutResult: string | void
```

I have other questions about this problem but first I need to understand the right way to express the relationship between the `Message` and `Result` types. Are my assumptions about the `Result` lookup correct? Should I be doing completely something different than using the union of tuples? Do I need to add some property to each Message to uniquely identify it? Something else?

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCIHsB2BTaBvAsAKGn6wyEALgE4CuwxCpAFAA7kBGIAlsNKSmACbIgBPTigC2CYigCqpEAC5oJUqyQBzAJQZoAXxw7sOUJBiwAFimABrBOWIYc+AkTKVqdRi3bDe-IU1JgkYBMAOTARFHlFZXVNPT0DcChoACUUADcABTBSCDQsXHxCJEUXGgZmNg4ubyRBaD8AoNDwyLJojXRtXRwcYgF6NAzScQRCEGgAXmgAbXhkFAAaaDSEVh4AXWgAHxnTcysbJZW1zZ3p1Mzs3KWo1XWe7D6BlJQIchBiAB4AWVeIMBUKAAfJNoABRAAeZDAVE+QxGYyW01+UABi2gAQE6yB0wAjPd9I9+mgAGpgNg8FH-QGg+HUMbTAAMBN6xOgABFWBB6GBiEEfn80dAUFCUEgeDAyRSqWiQVNaOFUYD5DLARoJiDUm8PgKlcCHkUSNAeFyeXyTPJOdzefy6aMECAmdjQbrqWgRRJxTA7QzmUCFYLldBVSh1SD8g5WAAzaABvXQZQkRooBAxuaoDr2Bz4AD0OeNCAIiFQCmI5CjUaz2eEZdISCrXQKeGjscVboTxWIydTcDMlmsxEzTezeYLBD7B1sJHLlcJ1bwo4gJmsIB4HYgXNsxBMvOgAEka+Q68tVmuzFwGw4uLWkNAAORLldrpDiepocmIADuKB4d4bekjGM43bRMu0CFMYwuLIclDOxhwcQ1bE6BpAhCMI0C0UE2zRS9c3zPhhDSHkYNLGdcLwa8j1vO8wCYYAeBQKNcQAJgAZgAFj-YcAPwbdhk-aBUAEsFSGGOgAAMAHUd1sLloG3LkAH5oAAEnQbDAS0cS1G6QlRwUmAuG1WSYCeH8O0IUTzGIOpIBwUdEKLeYtXeYhWiUVRthPNYDCcJzUBcj5QRNa1zVoIS4GLFBaDvExiGIehZDzFRWG3ZgADpCBEHMRAEHMuHoBA7zUHS9PzR93jXKMwFYcZP1Skx5LZFBRJoXzO3HfYB0CtyXmMz49n7Gw5XvW4VDvIA)

Comment: This may be useful: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know the use cases and the context of what you are trying to build, but I feel like `dispatch` returning different types is not a good practice here (there are some cases where it can be necessary : https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/225682/is-it-a-bad-idea-to-return-different-data-types-from-a-single-function-in-a-dyna ). You could use [Strategy Pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/strategy).

Anyway, let's say this use case is legit :

As you mentionned it, `Extract` matches both `Checkout` and `RevParse` when `Checkout` is given to Result.
Indeed, [Typescript doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttu) says :

> `Extract<T,U>` 
>   Constructs a type by extracting from T all properties that are assignable to U

In your case, `[Checkout, void]` and `[RevParse, string]` are assignable to `[Checkout, any]` (when you do Result)
It means `Checkout` and `RevParse` is assignable to `Checkout`, and `void` & `string` are assignable to `any`.

The reason is that for classes, Typescript uses structural typing as the following, according to the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#classes) :

> they (classes) have both a static and an instance type. When comparing two
>   objects of a class type, only members of the instance are compared.
>   Static members and constructors do not affect compatibility.

On the contrary

> Private and protected members in a class affect their compatibility.

Therefore, all that matters is the structure of a type, not the name of a type. If two types are structurally equivalent they are interchangeable. 
If you don't want that to happen, you can use "nominal typing". There are several approaches, although I think it should be use exceptionally as for now it is not yet native in Typescript. There is a current [PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/33038) so it might become native in TS soon, using "unique" keyword. For now :

1. You can add private property to your classes to make it different, even if they have a different name.

> 

```
class Clone {
    private __nominal: void;
    constructor(public readonly remoteUrl: string) { }
}

class Checkout {
    private __nominal: void;
    constructor(public readonly branchName: string) { }
}

class RevParse {
    private __nominal: void;
    constructor(public readonly branchName: string) { }
}
```

2. You can use static property with different names, using "Brand" suffix, as proposed and used by [Typescript team](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/7b48a182c05ea4dea81bab73ecbbe9e013a79e99/src/compiler/types.ts#L693-L698)

> 

```
class Clone {
    _cloneBrand: any;
    constructor(public readonly remoteUrl: string) { }
}

class Checkout {
    _checkoutBrand: any;
    constructor(public readonly branchName: string) { }
}

class RevParse {
    _revParseBrand: any;
    constructor(public readonly branchName: string) { }
}
```

This, will fix your second issue, it will become :

```
// const checkoutResult: void
```

For the dispatch function, you should just do the following, using your Result type already defined :

```
 const dispatch = <Message extends Protocol[0]>(message: Message): Result<Message> => {
    if (message instanceof Clone) {
        // do clone stuff
        return
    }
    if (message instanceof Checkout) {
        // do checkout stuff

        // should insist that I return void here
        return 'should not be allowed'
    }
    if (message instanceof RevParse) {
        const { branchName } = message
        // do revparse stuff
        return 'abcdef1234'
    }
    throw new Error(`What is this? ${message}`)
}
```

This will fix your first issue, typescript will now consider the return of `dispatch(new Clone('url'))` as void

Comment: Thanks!

Given a set of these types, is it possible to find out whether they're unique or not? Like, can I guard against people programming against my interface who forget to make their types unique? Is there a way to test that a set of them (either in a tuple or a union) is unique?

Comment: I can ask this as a separate question if you'd prefer :)

Comment: I don't think this is possible, did you try with this approach : [playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-sea-86h36)
In this case, any class you want to use should implement your command interface. 
Sorry, it really depends on the context and how you want to use theses classes, not sure if it helps.